# Can memcache tell you how much memory it is using?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, memcached

Can memcache tell you how much memory it is using in total?

How about for a particular key?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In php, but I'm sure you are able to translate to RoR:-

```
echo "You are using " . $memcache->getstats()["bytes"] . " of storage ";
echo "out of " . $memcache->getstats()["limit_maxbytes"];
```

See http://php.net/manual/en/memcache.getstats.php

Comment: that's probably replacing `$memcache->getstats()` with `memcache.stats`

Comment: In the interest of thoroughness, for those wanting the same info while using Memcached you can reference `reset($memcached->getStats())["bytes"]` with same result

Answer (score 24):

And on the command line, you could do this:

```
echo "stats" | nc 127.0.0.1 11211 | grep bytes
```